# Golang Multiple fields with same json tag name

Tags: json, go, struct

How do I unmarshal a JSON to a struct which contains 2 fields (`UserName` and `Name`) containing the same JSON Tag Name (`name`)?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    UserName string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Name     string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`
                {
                    "name":"kishore"
                }
            `)
    user := &User{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("value of user : %+v\n", user)
}
```

Actual Output:
`value of user : &{UserName: Name:}`

Expected Output:
`value of user : &{UserName:kishore Name:kishore}`

How do I get the `UserName` and `Name` field Populated with `kishore`?

When I look at the source code of [Json](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go) I see they discard if 2 top level fields have same tag name. But this comment in code made me think if there is a way to tag both `either both tagged or neither tagged`

```
func dominantField(fields []field) (field, bool) {
    // The fields are sorted in increasing index-length order, then by presence of tag.
    // That means that the first field is the dominant one. We need only check
    // for error cases: two fields at top level, either both tagged or neither tagged.
    if len(fields) > 1 && len(fields[0].index) == len(fields[1].index) && fields[0].tag == fields[1].tag {
        return field{}, false
    }
    return fields[0], true
}
```

Playground Link : https://play.golang.org/p/TN9IQ8lFR6a

Comment: Any reason for the down votes? Is the question missing some required info or Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It's in the docs. [`Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) says: "To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal", and [`Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) says: "If there is exactly one field (tagged or not according to the first rule), that is selected...Otherwise there are multiple fields, and all are ignored"

Comment: Put another way: `encoding/json` does not support multiple struct fields for the same JSON key. You'll have to do this yourself, either by implementing `UnmarshalJSON`, or by unmarshaling into one field and copying to the other yourself. However, I would very very strongly recommend a thorough code review, because there should be no situation where you actually need the described behavior if the design is correct.

Comment: @Adrian got it, so its not possible using a json marshaler. Actually there is a situation where this is needed for us. The same Name field gets stored in multiple fields with each having a different operation performed on them. The tags drive the operation on those fields, so before the tag operation kicks in we need all related fields to already be populated with that value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "before the tag operation kicks in" - struct field tags are compile-time, not run-time, they're not an "operation" and they don't execute.

Comment: No, its a custom logic. Based on certain tags we invoke few operations (methods) dynamically, which will work on those fields. NVM, I was just saying there is a use case where 2 fields need to have identical values prior to calling a method and their values get changed to different things inside that method. I just trying to use json to achieve this duplicate copy of values, instead of writing my own marshaler. So that was the question, it was more on how to copy a field value to another using tags. I thought maybe json could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a case of duplicate struct tags causing unmarshaller to ignore it. As per the official documentation - "3) Otherwise there are multiple fields, and all are ignored; no error occurs."

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

What you should probably do is "go vet" and see if your code has such issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
type User struct {
    UserName string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Name     string `json:"-"`
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type U User
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, (*U)(u)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    u.Name = u.UserName
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PRuigiBfwWv

Comment: I actually can't add methods to my struct (As this is dynamically created struct using reflection). Also, the manual assignment might become messy as there are about 4 fields which will have these duplicate tags and the only access I've to fields of this object is via reflection. The struct can contain nested object like []Dependents who internally will have duplicate tags with in that struct.